# Firebase authenticate error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm trying to make my first Ionic app with Firebase authentication.

When I try to authenticate my user I get this error:

> Q {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "signInWithPopup failed: First argument "authProvider" must be a valid Auth provider."}

[Here is an error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4S35.png)

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user- scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- compiled css output -->
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab-chat.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab-dash.css">         
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-app.js">  </script>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDPCScioFS49tW0rPCjQliUKh5j0Rcw72M",
  authDomain: "skinder-858b9.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://skinder-858b9.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "skinder-858b9.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "280323404236"
   };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
 </script>


<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>
<!--rsvp liv-->
<script src="lib/rsvp/rsvp.js"></script>
<!---->

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="lib/geofire/dist/geofire.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-elastic/elastic.js"></script>
<script src="lib/rxjs/dist/rx.lite.compat.js"></script> </head>
<script src="lib/angular-audio/app/angular.audio.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-rx/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/parse-js-sdk/lib/parse.js"></script>
<!-- -->
<script src="lib/angular-rx/dist/rx.angular.map"></script>
<!-- endbower -->

  <!-- inject:js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat/chat_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat/message_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat_post/post_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat_post/posts_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/dash_page/dash_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/dash_page/get_user_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/login/login_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/logout/logout_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/map/map_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/main/main_controller.js"></script>

<!-- endinject -->
  <!--for testing-->
  <!--todo remove in production-->
  <script src="js/services/state-watcher.service.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="skinder">
<!--
  The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
-->
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<!--
  The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
  Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
  have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
-->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

My login controller:

```
 /*global Firebase*/
 (function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDPCScioFS49tW0rPCjQliUKh5j0Rcw72M",
    authDomain: "skinder-858b9.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://skinder-858b9.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "skinder-858b9.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "280323404236"
         };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    angular.module('skinder')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseAuth',     '$window', '$rootScope', '$state', LoginCtrl]);
  function LoginCtrl($scope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, FBURL, USERURL, $window,  $rootScope, $state) {
  //var fbRef = new Firebase("https://skinder-858b9.firebaseio.com");
  var fbRef = firebase.database().ref();
  //var authObj = $firebaseAuth(fbRef);

  //var userRef = new Firebase(USERURL);
  //todo adding checking user data
  //var isNewUser = true;

  var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  $scope.login = function (provider) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData);
        $rootScope.userKey = authData.uid;
        $state.go('tab.dash');
        //todo refactor this to service
        //add new user ref to fireabase
        userRef.child(authData.uid).set({
          provider: authData.provider,
          user_name: authData.facebook.displayName,
          picture: authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url
        });
        return authData;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
      });
  };

  //$scope.simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef);
  //$scope.errors = [];
  //$scope.user = {
  //  email: '',
  //  password: ''
  //};
  //
  //$scope.login = function() {
  //  $scope.errors = [];
  //
  //  if ($scope.user.email === '') {
  //    $scope.errors.push('Please enter your email');
  //  }
  //
  //  if ($scope.user.password === '') {
  //    $scope.errors.push('Please enter your password');
  //  }
  //
  //  if ($scope.errors.length > 0) {
  //    return;
  //  }
  //
  //  var promise = $scope.simpleLogin.$login('password', {
  //    email: $scope.user.email,
  //    password: $scope.user.password
  //  });
  //
  //  promise.then(function(user) {
  //    console.log(user);
  //    $rootScope.user = user;
  //    $window.location.href = '/#/main';
  //  }, function(error) {
  //    console.error(error);
  //    if (error.code === 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
  //      $scope.errors.push('The email was invalid');
  //    }
  //    if (error.code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
  //      $scope.errors.push('The password was invalid');
  //    }
  //  });
  //
  //};

   }

  }(window.angular));
```

I am using Firebase 3.6.2 along with AngularFire 2.0.1

Comment: You must not be passing the correct provider. In your code, you are defining the provider outside of $scope.login function. When login is called, the provider is not being passed. Try logging the provider argument to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the provider within your *login* function. I am guessing you are calling this function on some button click and you are not passing a valid provider refference. So instead of what you did here:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
$scope.login = function (provider) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function(authData) { ...
```

You need to do something like this:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function(authData) { ...
```